# Installing pocketsphinx python module: command 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_wininst'

Tags: python-3.x

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

command: 'C:\Users\Sumant Ku Dubey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Sumant Ku Dubey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f9pe9apw\pocketsphinx_4bf3d77c687d4ae687d62f42ab85aec1\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Sumant Ku Dubey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f9pe9apw\pocketsphinx_4bf3d77c687d4ae687d62f42ab85aec1\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Sumant Ku Dubey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ak1nlos1'
cwd: C:\Users\Sumant Ku Dubey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f9pe9apw\pocketsphinx_4bf3d77c687d4ae687d62f42ab85aec1
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\Sumant Ku Dubey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f9pe9apw\pocketsphinx_4bf3d77c687d4ae687d62f42ab85aec1\setup.py", line 21, in 
from distutils.command.bdist_wininst import bdist_wininst as _bdist_wininst
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_wininst'

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was able to deal with it by downgrading to python 3.6
The problem is, that distutils was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The bdist_wininst format was deprecated in Python 3.8, and the documentation for this format has been removed in Python 3.9. The recommended way to distribute Python packages now is the Wheel format.
you can overcome this error by updating the setuptools
`pip install --upgrade setuptools`